# Can a reordering happen in the presence of a volatile variable?

Tags: java, volatile

I am doing as follows, there's only 2 threads in my program.

```
// Thread 1
write a = 0
write a = 1
write volatile b = 1

// Thread 2
read volatile b // this I always do after write volatile b in the 1st thread
read a
```

I've read on Java Memory Model and from what I understand in thread 2 `read a` will ALWAYS give me 1.

I would like to know if this my understanding is correct or not.

In particular CAN A REORDERING still HAPPEN so I see a = 0 in the 2nd thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are mostly correct.  However, i would restate it slightly to match what the JMM guarantees.

If Thread 2 reads `b` *and sees value 1*, then the subsequent read of `a` will be 1.  Like you said, if Thread 2 always reads `b` "after" Thread 1 finishes writing it, then Thread 2 will see the value 1 and the read of `a` will be as you expect.

Comment: I still don't understand why a reordering can not happen in the thread 1. Why a can not be 0? Oh alas, I just don't get it, could you, please, refer me to the JLS spec where it says so?

Comment: @Alex - the answer to the linked question references the JLS.  basically, you can't move any writes to after a volatile write and you can't move any reads to before a volatile read.